# Upload the same file into multiple folders

Tags: php, file, upload

I have an uploading form, and when i select the file,i need it to be uploaded in multiple folders.Any ideas how to do that? I've tried with a loop like the following one:

```
foreach($_POST['check'] as $check){     
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['doc']['tmp_name'], $target_path);
    chmod($target_path,0777);    
}
```

But it only upload once.Any ideas please?

Comment: $target_path has to exists, otherwise before moving you have to create the path. This for every path you want to move the file to.

Comment: @Masiorama comeone .... you really think the path its empty? I just didn't wrote the entire code,because it's pretty simple to catch the idea....

Comment: I can judge only what I see, not guess what's in your mind. Wide the question or you will get more "useless" comments, I fear.

Comment: thats not a good idea, why you need same file on 3 places. you can just use same file on diffrent location using url. I am not sure why you want that. just use `copy()` after upload. it will be not easy to maintain

Comment: @Masiorama from the question it's clear that OP succeeds in uploading the file to one destination, so what you're saying is completely irrelevant.

Comment: @CamilStaps if he wants to upload in multiple destinations (despite the fact that he can copy after the first upload), don't those destinations have to exist?

Comment: @Masiorama naturally, and besides that you could also mention that PHP has to be installed on the machine. It's something else which is true and is not going to help OP at all because he _knows_ that and the _problem clearly is not there_.

Comment: @CamilStaps well, I think you are taking too many things for granted, but whatever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After uploading, copy the file from the target path to the other paths with [copy()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php).

```
foreach($_POST['check'] as $check){     
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['doc']['tmp_name'], $target_path);
    chmod($target_path,0777);    
    // and now...
    copy($target_path, $target_path_2);
    copy($target_path, $target_path_3);
    // etc...
}
```

By the way, setting 0777 for permissions generally is unnecessary and a bad idea. You want anyone to upload files and let any user execute them? That's the way to start giving anyone full control over your machine.

Also, are you sure that you need the file on multiple places? Why not have one common storage folder and create symbolic links to it? But that depends on your setup, of course.

Comment: Thanks it works.Dont worry,i'm not letting anyone to acces this engine.

Comment: @PetruLebada great. Though still, try to always have the permissions as limited as possible, that's good practice.

Answer (score 1):

Upload once and then just [copy()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php) it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$i = 0; 
foreach($_POST['check'] as $check){ 
   $basePath = "/var/www/html/more/phpexm/"; 
   $target_path = $basePath . $check; 

   if (!file_exists($target_path)){ 
       mkdir($target_path, 0777);
   }

   if ($i == 0){
       $sFileNameTmp = $_FILES['doc']['tmp_name'];
       $sFileName = $_FILES['doc']['name'];
       move_uploaded_file($sFileNameTmp, $target_path . '/' . $sFileName);
       $sFirstFileUploaded = $target_path; 
   }
   else{ 
       copy ($sFirstFileUploaded . '/' . $sFileName,  $target_path  . '/' . $sFileName); 
    }
    $i++;   
}
```

Comment: I have tested on my linux machine

Comment: thanks but it worked with just one copy() instead of move_uploaded_file